# Float a div next to a checkbox

Tags: html, css

I have a container div of set width that contains a checkbox and a label. The problem is that instead of floating next to the checkbox, the label is under the checkbox. How can I make the label float next to the checkbox. This is the HTML and CSS and I have a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7np4y68k/) here.

```
<div id="CheckboxContainer">
<input type="checkbox" id="TheCheckbox" />
<div id="TheCheckboxLabel">
This text should float next to the checkbox instead of being under.
</div>
</div>

#CheckboxContainer{width:300px;margin:20px auto;background:red;overflow:hidden;}
#TheCheckbox{float:left;display:inline-block;margin:10px 10px;}
#TheCheckboxLabel{float:left;display:inline-block;margin:10px 10px;}
```

Comment: Why do you need it to float? Default behaviour https://jsfiddle.net/7np4y68k/1/

Comment: use only float:left on id "TheCheckbox" and remove display:inline-block from both id TheCheckbox and TheCheckboxLable [ https://jsfiddle.net/g2vzycsa/1/ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float only `#TheCheckbox`, and add `overflow: hidden;` on `#TheCheckboxLabel`.

```css
#CheckboxContainer {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#TheCheckbox {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}
#TheCheckboxLabel {
  margin: 10px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="CheckboxContainer">
  <input type="checkbox" id="TheCheckbox" />
  <div id="TheCheckboxLabel">
    This text should float next to the checkbox instead of being under.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove float from `TheCheckboxLabel` and change display to `block`. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7np4y68k/2/

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that easily.

```css
#CheckboxContainer{width:300px;margin:20px auto;background:red;display:flex;}
```

```html
<div id="CheckboxContainer">
<input type="checkbox" id="TheCheckbox" />
<div id="TheCheckboxLabel">
This text should float next to the checkbox instead of being under.
</div>
</div>
```